# How do I change the colour of ShareActionProvider?

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I am using a `android.widget.ShareActionProvider` to show a share icon on my menu bar. However, my menu bar background is white and I would like to make my icon black. Is there a way to do it?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:title="Share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

[Screenshot of my menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DzvN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If action bar is dark, it will turn the image logo to white
and if action bar light, it will turn the image logo to black[image]